# How can I check if a generic method parameter is a value type?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, value-type, reference-type

Is there a way to check if a variable is value type of reference type?

Imagine:

```
private object GetSomething<T>(params T[] values) 
{
    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        bool is ValueType; // Check if 'value' is a value type or reference type
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Do you want to know whether a particular variable *contains* a value type, or *can only contain a particular value type* by the generic construction? A variable might be of type object, and contain a boxed int. It's contents are a value type but the variable is not restricted to only containing ints. Which do you care about, and why?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
bool isValueType = typeof(T).IsValueType;
```

Job done... it doesn't matter if any of the values is `null`, and it works even for an empty array.

Comment: caveat: if you wanted to provide a pathological edge-case, let `T` be `object`, and let the values be boxed structs.

Comment: The type of the method parameter in that case would be System.Object, which is a class type, and *variables of type T will have reference semantics, even when the underlying object is a boxed struct*.  For example, suppose `T` is a generic constrained to `IEnumerator<Integer>`, and `x` and `y` are variables of type `T`.  If `T` is a struct type, `x=y` may copy the enumerator state; if `T` is a reference type, *even if that object is a boxed struct*, `x` would share `y`'s state.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition will look like

```
var cond = false;
if(value != null) 
  cond = value.GetType().IsValueType
```

Comment: Actually, this is not safe, since `value` can potentially be `null` for both ref-type and value-type (the latter via `Nullable<T>`)

Comment: Playing with fire. `value` could be null :-)

Comment: I see, hunting for reputation points took over my coder brain.

Comment: @KarelFrajtak: Even if `value` is not null, the specified test won't report the type of the generic parameter.  For example, if `T` is `System.Object` and `Values[0]` is a boxed integer, the first time through the loop, `value.GetType().IsValueType` will report `True` even though the generic method parameter `T` is `System.Object`, which is definitely not a value type.